# any way to save multiple plots in for loop without overwriting in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

I have a list of aggregated dataframes that hold trade statistics of different countries. I am able to make the respective plot by looping through this dataframe list. Now I intend to save those locally without overwriting, I mean saving each plot with its respective title name. To do so, I tried the following:

I have list of dataframe which have the following name:

```
[dfList[i].name for i in range(len(dfList))]

['AR  fresh-Beef-E',
 'AUC  fresh-Beef-E',
 'BR  fresh-Beef-E',
 'CA  fresh-Beef-E',
 'CL  fresh-Beef-E',
 'CN  fresh-Beef-E',
 'E28  fresh-Beef-E',
 'EG  fresh-Beef-E',
 'IN  fresh-Beef-E',
 'JP  fresh-Beef-E',
 'KR  fresh-Beef-E',
 'MX  fresh-Beef-E',
 'NZ  fresh-Beef-E',
 'PY  fresh-Beef-E',
 'US  fresh-Beef-E',
 'UY  fresh-Beef-E',
 'ZA  fresh-Beef-E']
```

**current attempt**:

intend to save figure locally with its plot title as filename:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

outpath = r'C:/Users/plots'

if os.path.exists(outpath):
    shutil.rmtree(outpath)
_ = os.mkdir(outpath)

for i in range(len(dfList)) :
    plt.figure()
    my_plotter(dfList[i],title=dfList[i].name)
    plt.savefig(path.join(outpath,"dataname_{0}.png".format(i)))
    plt.close()
```

**new update**

here is how my plotting function looks like:

```
def my_plotter(df, plot_type='something', ylab_nm='something', title=None):
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
    if plot_type=='something':
        _ = df.plot(kind='line', ax=ax1, marker='o', ls='-', linewidth=2, color=colors)
    else:
        df.loc[:, 'Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
        _ = df.div(df.Total, axis=0).iloc[:, :-1].plot(kind='line', ax=ax1, marker='o', ls='--', linewidth=4, color=colors)
        df.drop('Total', axis=1, inplace=True)
        ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter(xmax=1, decimals=0))
        ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=1, interval=3))

    ax1.set(title=title)
    plt.title(title)
    ax1.xaxis.label.set_visible(False)
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.show()
```

but the above attempt didn't save the plot to the local directory. I looked into `SO` and tried possible suggestion but I still didn't get all plots which supposed to be named by taking its plot title and saved to the local file directory. In my attempt, none of the plots were saved to a local directory.

Can anyone point me out how to make this work? any idea?
**goal**

I intend to save each plot by taking its title as the filename and save it to the local directory. Any thoughts? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a complete MWE, but I think the fixes below should help you out.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os

# Only need to set the style once (not in loop)
plt.style.use('ggplot')

outpath = r'C:/Users/plots'

def my_plotter(df, plot_type='something', ylab_nm='something', title=None):
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    if plot_type=='something':
        # Plots on ax1, so don't save output as another ax instance
        df.plot(kind='line', ax=ax1, marker='o', ls='-', linewidth=2)
    else:
        df.loc[:, 'Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
        # Plots on ax1, so don't save output as another ax instance
        df.div(df.Total, axis=0).iloc[:, :-1].plot(kind='line', ax=ax1, marker='o', ls='--', linewidth=4, color=colors)
        df.drop('Total', axis=1, inplace=True)
        ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter(xmax=1, decimals=0))
        ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=1, interval=3))

    ax1.set(title=title)
    ax1.set_title(title, size=24, verticalalignment='bottom') 
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b %Y'))
    ax1.xaxis.label.set_visible(False)

    plt.xticks(rotation=90)
    plt.show()
    return fig, ax1

if os.path.exists(outpath):
    shutil.rmtree(outpath)
_ = os.mkdir(outpath)

for i in range(len(dfList)):
    fig, ax1 = my_plotter(dfList[i], title=dfList[i].name)
    fig.savefig(path.join(outpath,"dataname_{}.png".format(dfList[i].name)))
    plt.close()
```

Comment: I got type error when I tried this: `TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`. This attempt also not going to save figure by taking plot title name as file name. Any better idea?

Comment: Try ```import os.path as path``` at the top of your script

Comment: @ Ralph it is saved now but become file size `2kb` only means that actual generated figures are not saved correctly. why is that? Any better idea?

Comment: Are they just empty figures and axes? what does ```my_plotter``` do?

Comment: yes, it is empty figure. `my_plotter` make line chart for time series data.

Comment: ```plt.figure()``` creates an empty figure. You then attempt to plot on it with ```my_plotter```, but I'm guessing something goes wrong there (the figure you plot on isn't returned, maybe). and then you just save the empty figure.

Comment: If you can share ```my_plotter``` I think we can fix this.

Comment: I just posted my plotting function, any idea why I got empty figure? thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208136/discussion-between-beyond-inifinity-and-ralph).